# PHP-Regular expression to only match words in a string without a specific character

Tags: php, regex

I have the following PHP regex to match a word starting with the letter 'Z'.

```
/^Z/
```

How could I extend this regex to only match words starting with 'Z', but without a 'h' letter.

My code is

```
if(preg_match('/^Z/','Zoe, Zoey, Zoho, Zander, Zap',$matches)){
    echo $matches[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `[^h]` object to match anything except h, `\W` to exclude non-word characters, and the the `\b` word boundry.

`^Z[^h\W]+\b`

Answer (score 0):

> `How could I extend this regex to only match words starting with 'Z', but without a 'h' letter.`

You can use:

```
'/^Z[^h\W]*\b/'
```

Comment: you forgot an underscore `_`

Comment: I usually exclude the underscore `[^h\W_]`

Answer (score 0):

Use regex pattern `\bZ[a-gi-z]*\b`